# Trying to concatenate keras models: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)

Tags: python, keras, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two parallel models in keras, each with different inputs. The relevant code is below.

```
# model 1
model1_in = Input(shape=(train_x_1.shape[1], train_x_1.shape[2]))
model1_out = LSTM(50, activation='relu',return_sequences=False, name='layer_1')(model1_in)
model1 = Model(model1_in, model1_out)

# model 2
model2_in = Input(shape=(1))
model2_out = Dense(8, activation='relu', name='layer_2')(model2_in)
model2 = Model(model2_in, model2_out)

concatenated = concatenate(inputs=[model1.output, model2.output])
out = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='output_layer')(concatenated)
model = Model([model1_in, model2_in], out)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')


# fit network
history = model.fit([train_x_1,train_x_2], train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=72, validation_data=([test_x_1,test_x_2], test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

The error I'm getting is

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

and occurs at the model.fit line.

I'm running in IDLE. The train and test values are all arrays, and I've checked that all training inputs are of the same length:

```
#train_x_1.shape[0]
15465
#train_y.shape[0]
15465
#train_x_2.shape[0]
15465
#test_x_1.shape[0]
1719
#test_x_2.shape[0]
1719
#test_y.shape[0]
1719
#test_x_1
array([[[0.6243922 ],
        [0.5463666 ],
        [0.7083546 ], ... etc ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated- thanks in advance!

Full error trace is as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "*filepath*.py", line 220,
>   in 
>       history = model.fit([train_x_1,train_x_2], train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=72, validation_data=([test_x_1,test_x_2], test_y),
>   verbose=2, shuffle=False)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 728, in fit
>       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
>       distribution_strategy=strategy)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 547, in _process_training_inputs
>       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 606, in _process_inputs
>       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py",
>   line 217, in **init**
>       x = _process_numpy_inputs(x)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py",
>   line 703, in _process_numpy_inputs
>       inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_non_tensor, inputs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/nest.py",
>   line 535, in map_structure
>       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/nest.py",
>   line 535, in 
>       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py",
>   line 700, in _convert_non_tensor
>       return ops.convert_to_tensor(x)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1184, in convert_to_tensor
>       return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1242, in convert_to_tensor_v2
>       as_ref=False)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1296, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py",
>   line 52, in _default_conversion_function
>       return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 227, in constant
>       allow_broadcast=True)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 235, in _constant_impl
>       t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
>       return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype) ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type
>   float).

Comment: please add your full error trace.

Comment: @VivekMehta thanks - have just added

Comment: SOLVED: The values of x_2 were all as type float, whilst the x_1 values were as float32.
.astype('float32')
solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the Solution in Answer Section (even though it is present in the Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

The values of x_2 were all as type **`float`**, whilst the **`x_1 values`** were as **`float32`**.

Modifying **`x2`** to **`float32`** using **`x2.astype('float32')`** has resolved the issue.